# The amount of the DMF in the Sonogashira coupling - why it is of importance?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solvents

I was looking for some protocols for Sonogashira coupling and have found that in many papers the amount of the DMF used is exactly 2 ml per mole of the substrate.

Is there any reason for that? Usually, for other reactions, we can see, that articles report more-less random amount of solvents, like 10, 50, 100 ml - some "simple" numbers. But in this case I see numbers like 68 ml (why not 70?). Why must it be exactly 2 ml/mole?

some refs:

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/ol049474j/suppl_file/ol049474jsi20040410_035107.pdf

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040402000008772

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/jo8020264/suppl_file/jo8020264_si_001.pdf

Comment: I for my part did a Sonogashira reaction with very good yields and without any DMF at all.

Comment: Did you use any solvent, or just the liquid reactants? Do you have any procedure that I could read? Thanks!

Comment: Triethylamine was the solvent. Source: Y. Fan, Y.-M. Zhu, F.-R. Dai, L.-Y. Zhang, Z.-N. Chen *Dalton Trans.* **2007**, 3885. DOI: [10.1039/b707797a](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/b707797a).